# eBay API: retrieve full item listing by SiteID

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-lms

Does anyone know how to retrieve a full listing of items by Site (ebay.us, ebay.fr ..) using ebay API?
I am using the Large Merchant Service because I manage thousands of items on each site (about 100k).
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/large-merchant-services/concepts/lms_apiguide.html

**1st solution i have tried (Active Inventory Report) According the doc :
Retrieving an Active Inventory Report**

> The ActiveInventoryReportRequest allows you to download a description
>   of all of your active listings by SKU. The SKU details include ItemID,
>   Price, Quantity, SKU, and SiteID.

I have checked with premium support and there is a mistake, `SiteID` is never included in response.

**2nd solution (GetSellerList)**

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

According to the docs:

> GetSellerList returns a maximum of 5,000 items per call (this is possible if you do not specify a Detail Level, and thus return the
>   smallest set of data for each item). However, if you specify any
>   DetailLevel value (and thus increase the fields returned for each
>   item), you might need to use Pagination values to obtain the complete
>   result set. If you use a DetailLevel, the response can contain no more
>   than 200 items per call.

So can not use this one because of limitation to 5000 items and I do not know when items have been added, a few years ago for a bunch of them.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can get lots more than 5,000 results with GetSellerList, but you are right you can only get 200 at a time. The code below is part of a loop iterating through until HasMoreItems is false. The code is written in Perl and uses Net::eBay to connect.

```
my $result = $eBay->submitRequest( "GetSellerList",
                               {
                UserID => "$ebay_settings{'ebay_account'}",

                GranularityLevel => 'Medium',

                EndTimeFrom => "$start_time",

                EndTimeTo => "$end_time",

                                    Pagination => {
                                                  EntriesPerPage => 200,
                                                  PageNumber => $page_number
                                                  }


                               }
                             );



if( ref $result ) {

$result->{HasMoreItems} eq "false" and $done = "Y";

}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I have done the same thing with php, eBay will perhaps consider add SiteID in LMS in next release ..